# My code is running properly in pandas, but not in modin

Tags: python, pandas, csv, concatenation, modin

when i use pandas, the code works perfect ( but very slow ), 
and when use modin, and concat dataframe, shows me an aerror

```
contador = 0
df = pd.DataFrame()
data = pd.DataFrame()

for file in range(len(files)):
    usefile = files[file]
    print("Valor Numero :" + str(contador) + " de un total de " + str((len(files))) + " archivos")
    print("Existe " + str(usefile) + " añadiendolo al DataFrame" )
    contador = contador +1
    ruta = mainpath + "/" + str(usefile) 
    df = pd.read_csv(ruta)
    datos[usefile] = df
data = pd.concat(datos.values(), keys=datos.keys() , sort='True')
```

### I expect the output of a dataframe with all files concatenate from dict, but y recive ( in pandas , all works perfect ) :

```
<ipython-input-4-e5a361476e76> in <module>
     12     df = pd.read_csv(ruta)
     13     datos[usefile] = df
---> 14 data = pd.concat(datos.values(), keys=datos.keys() , sort='True')
     15 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/modin/pandas/concat.py in concat(objs, axis, join, join_axes, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, sort, copy)
     98         new_idx_labels = {
     99             keys[i]: objs[i].index if axis == 0 else objs[i].columns
--> 100             for i in range(len(objs))
    101         }
    102         print(new_idx_labels)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/modin/pandas/concat.py in <dictcomp>(.0)
     98         new_idx_labels = {
     99             keys[i]: objs[i].index if axis == 0 else objs[i].columns
--> 100             for i in range(len(objs))
    101         }
    102         print(new_idx_labels)

TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: That looks like a mismatch  between libraries for Python 2 and 3

Comment: I have no idea how this codebase appears for Python 3.7 but it appears to be meant for Python 2

Answer (score 1):

This is behavior that is unintentionally not yet supported in Modin (version 0.4) based on an assumption that the `keys` and `objs` parameters are subscriptable.

The last line in your code can be changed as a workaround until it is fixed in Modin:

```
data = pd.concat(list(datos.values()), keys=list(datos.keys()) , sort='True')
```

I created an issue on the Modin repo to track the issue: https://github.com/modin-project/modin/issues/557